# how to use ternary operator to write this if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, pep

```
def get(count=None): 
    if count >= 1: 
        a = count - 1
    else: 
        a = 0
    return a
```

Everything is in the title.. Just for sport.

Thank you

Comment: what is `replies`?

Comment: This code will sometimes fail in Python 3.x.

Comment: @ignacio this is a 2.7 matter but why is that in python 3 ?

Comment: Because you'd be comparing `None` to an `int`.

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow, please try http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean by 'best', that's subjective.

Comment: `return max(0, count - 1)`

Comment: @ignacio actually I removed the None treatment for clarity but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean using a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/1561176)?

```
a = count - 1 if count >= 1 else 0
```

---

Your code will fail if `count` is `None` because you can't compare nonetypes to integers. But my answer is how you would write this conditional statement in a  "better" way.

---

Thus - I would write the function like this (Thanks [@poke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050459/best-pythonic-way-to-write-this-if-statement/37050518#comment61648399_37050459) for the `max` idea.):

```
def get(count=None):
    return max(count-1, 0) if isinstance(count, int) else 0
```

Comment: Exactly, thanks ! I tried before but could only return a boolean.